# Activity won't finish onbackpressed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am learning to develop Android apps and currently using Android Studio. I've created two activities to test the program: a splash screen and a menu/home activity. I'm doing quite fine with the layout design, but I have encountered some programming troubles: When I press "Back" on my emulator, my home activity doesn't finish and exit the app. Only after the second press I manage to quit it. My splash screen is doing just fine, however that's not the case for the home activity. It looks like the activity restarts (even though to start it I used an explicit intent. I tried adding android:noHistory="true" to the manifest. I tried some onbackpressed, doubleBackToExitPressedOnce codes I found online, but no luck. I am not quite sure what the default setting are, but nothing seems to work. I don't know if I'm skipping something. I hope you can help me. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.apptest" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home_screen"
            android:noHistory="true">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

```
public class HomeScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.homescreen);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_splash_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
    ImageView flashscreenView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashscreenanimation);
    flashscreenView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.flashscreenanimation);
    AnimationDrawable flashscreenanimation = (AnimationDrawable) flashscreenView.getBackground();
    flashscreenanimation.start();

 Thread loading = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(2730);
                finish();
                Intent splash = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);
                startActivity(splash);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
        }
    };

    loading.start();
}
```

}

Comment: Please post main parts of your code

Comment: Just posted my manifest and home java.

Comment: Could you please share the part where you start the HomeScreen Activity? What I assume is happening is that the HomeScreen Activity gets added to the backstack twice.

Comment: @ILUXONCHIK I think that's exactly what happens. I will update the post with the splash screen explicit intent.

Comment: because you are starting your activity two times. one in try block and other in finally block. place your code in either block, would be better if your remove finally

Comment: @KaranMer I just realized that, I removed the finally intent and leave it blank and kept the try one. But still same result. I will try with this android:launchMode="singleTask", but I am not sure if that's convenient though.

Comment: @MatejVarga also in your try use code like this `Intent splash = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);
                finish();startActivity(splash);`

Comment: call finish(); before starting new activity

Comment: @KaranMer After creating a blank activity and linking it to the intent, I just realised that the emulator is not updating. You were right, it works as expected now in my phone. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@KaranMer helped me solve this. I had two intents (one in try and the other in finallyand I just had to get rid of one.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of emulator try using in mobile device.

Comment: Just did, it works now with Karan Mer answer (on question comments) in case someone has the same problem.

Answer (score -3):

Override onBackPressed() method in your HomeScreen Activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 finish();
}
```

Comment: @Matej Varga In your case onBackPressesed() is calling at  second click. Just write oneToast message and confirm it whether it is calling at first or second click. Just tell me what kind of stuff you are doing in your HomeScreen Activity

Comment: It will be a home menu with some buttons, but first I wanted to solve this issue. How can I write a Toast? Will that finish the activity on first click?

Comment: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

Comment: It doesn't make it quit in one click, thanks though.

Comment: `finishAffinity();` instead of `finish();` Note: require minSdkVersion 16